# AIX: meaning of lslpp type-column

Tags: aix

Running `lslpp -L` yields the following (shortened) output:

```
Fileset                      Level  State  Type  Description (Uninstaller)
  ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
  DirectorCommonAgent        6.3.3.1    C     F    All required files of...
```

What does the Type-column mean and what are the valid types?
Neither `man lslpp` nor IBM's own [documentation](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_71/com.ibm.aix.cmds3/lslpp.htm) seems to specify this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to do with the type of image that was last applied for that lpp.  For all practical purposes, you will see "I" for install images and "F" for update images.  There can also be "M" which is for a "cumulative update" or a "maintenance level update" but I've never seen it used, and "E" which appears to be something specific for English.

Comment: Do you have som reference to back this up?

Comment: No, I can't find a publicly available reference.  You can go pull down all the install images at fix central which I happen to have at my disposal already.  Inside each is an lpp_name that is used by inutoc to create a .toc file.  The format is here: https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_aix_61/com.ibm.aix.genprogc/pkging_sw4_install.htm It is outdated and incomplete but look at field 3 "Package Type" and it has four values.  That maps to the "type" listed in lslpp output.